# Поиск в textBox по вводимым символам по коллекции

Tags: c#, текст, textbox

Задача загрузить коллекцию с городами из базы и пользователь вводит одну букву и снизу показываются все элементы из коллекции в которых есть эта буква, вводит вторую и отсев идет дальше, потом он выбирает город и его передавать дальше параметром.
Подскажите, какой из элементов выбрать из textBox, richtextbox или лучше использовать другой какой-то элемент более подходящий для этого. И как это реализовать ?

Comment: Может Combobox?

Comment: А как реализовать поиск по вводимым символам ?

Comment: Такие компоненты уже реализованы, например у DevExpress

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825804/7482894